# Having trouble deploying to google cloud platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, conda

I have successfully deployed the application locally from my conda enviornment using `uvicorn main:app` but when I attempt to deploy to Google Cloud Platform using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` I'm getting an error which I find difficult to debug. Here is what I am getting

```
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
  0%|          | 0/6892 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Skipping token 2519370 with 1-dimensional vector ['300']; likely a header
    self.stop()
 39%|███▉      | 1225/3132 [00:00<00:00, 2785.15it/s]  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
  0%|          | 0/7657 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Skipping token 2519370 with 1-dimensional vector ['300']; likely a header
 56%|█████▌    | 1711/3045 [00:00<00:00, 3331.80it/s]:35, 705kB/s]
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
resources:
  cpu: 12
  memory_gb: 72
  disk_size_gb: 60
instance_class: F4_1G
entrypoint: gunicorn main:app -w 24 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

requirements.txt

```
certifi
click
fastapi
gunicorn
h11
numpy
nltk
pandas
Pillow
pydantic
python-dateutil
pytz
six
starlette
torch
torchvision
uvicorn
websockets
wincertstore
pytorch-nlp
unidecode
google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: you are deploying your whole environment? try to reploy just the files for the app (.py files, requirements.txt, app.yaml and essentials)

Comment: Yes. I am deploying just the .py file with some .txt files.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml and your requirements.txt? Optionally, your project structure also

Comment: I added the yaml and the .txt file.

Comment: Have you solved it? If not try adding `-b :$PORT` to gunicorm command.

Comment: Can you share your project structure? Wondering if  main:app accessible to run by gunicorn? You can go through this video as a reference https://youtu.be/RaUO8mZJPN8